# How to terminate a process using local address without using PID in windows?

Tags: process

I'm working with terminating specific process using local address or port, not with the PID in Windows.

Comment: what do you mean by local address...?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't CMD

```
taskkill /s localaddress /im notepad.exe
```

will do?
e.g.

```
taskkill /s 192.168.0.4 /im notepad.exe
```

kiling notepad for machine 192.168.0.4

You may want to consider the current login if it has permission to do that in the target machine
check
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx
for the /u and /p

Comment: thanks for ur answer,but If two notepads are running and I wants to close specific or only one notepad? then It won't works.It'll terminates two notepads.

Comment: That is exactly why PID is required.
If situation allows, please use
tasklist /s localaddress to get the list of processes then Kill it via PID

Comment: can I retrieve the only PID from netstat command?  I am receiving the entire table.  ex:netstat -a -n -o | find "33333"

Comment: I dont really get the objective of doing that. You probably can export the output of netstat and check the PID it in text file etc.
like. netstat -ano | find "3333" > somewhere.txt